# What would cause a php script to just stop without reason?

Tags: php

I'm using [class.upload.php](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm) to upload images to a page. It seems a script that previously worked is now basically stopping part way through without any errors. At each line in the script, I'm echoing a number so I can get an idea at which point it stops, ie:

```
// save uploaded image with a new name
$foo->file_new_name_body = $image_name;
$foo->Process($save_directory);

if ($foo->processed) {
echo 'original image copied 1';
} else {
echo 'error 1: ' . $foo->error;
}

echo '1';    $foo->file_new_name_body = $image_name . '_medium';


echo '2';    $foo->image_resize = true;


echo '3';    $foo->image_convert = jpg;


echo '4';    $foo->image_x = 300;


echo '5';    $foo->image_ratio_y = true;


echo '6';    $foo->file_overwrite = true;


echo '7';    $foo->Process($save_directory);


echo '8';

if ($foo->processed) {
echo 'original image copied';
} else {
echo 'error 2: ' . $foo->error;
}
```

Output:

```
original image copied 1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

I have no way to explain it. No errors. No feedback. No further code after echo '7'; is executed. What is going on? How can I debug?

What would be causing this kind of behaviour?

**Edit**
I was able to fix the issue simply by changing the file being uploaded. It was 2000px wide and when I saved it as a smaller 800px image it completed the process.

I changed the memory as suggested to 40m, however this still doesn't let me process a 2000px wide image which doesn't really make much sense to me. How much memory is needed to deal with files these sizes?

Comment: Where is the variable `$save_directory` initialized and what is it initialized to?

Comment: Scripts don't stop for no reason. See what is in `Process`...

Comment: change the `class.upload.php` :)

Comment: @jonathan - $save_directory is the path to put the files. This variable shouldn't be the problem because the first instance of $foo->Process($save_directory) works just fine.

Comment: @xdazz - nothing is being added to the error_log when I execute the above unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your memory limit, I find that if I hit that, PHP can (does?) just quit without saying anything.

Comment: It seems the issue was the image being too large. And there was no error being thrown. Simply uploading a smaller image worked. Quite useless debugging without any errors showing up onscreen or in the logs.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not quite sure when it does and doesn't give you an error for running out of memory. I definitely have seen 'out of memory' errors before (especially with MySQL) but then again, I've had lots of times when it doesn't :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm no rocket scientist <sup>(a)</sup> but it seems to me that the most likely cause is that you're not exiting from the call to `$foo->Process($save_directory)`.

You probably need to debug that little beast to find out the reason why.

First step would be to output `$save_directory` and `$image_name` to see what they contain.

Second, I would comment out all those flag setting statements and see if it works with just the copy. Then add them back in one at a time until it starts failing again.

It may be that there's either a bug in the conversion code or something wrong with the uploaded image file which causes it to hang. If the latter, perhaps another (simpler) image file may work - it's worth checking.

It's no surprise that it would hang at that point, since all the other statement are simply setting up flags for the `process` call.

And, as a last resort, you have access to [the source](http://www.verot.net/download/class.upload.php/class.upload.txt). You can simply make your own copy of it (if you don't already have one) and insert debug statements into that to see where it's stopping.

The code for `process` is actually quite logically laid out. It appears to be a succession of blocks of the form:

```
if ($this->processed) {
    # Attempt to do next stage, setting
    #   $this->processed to false if there's a problem.
}
```

So you could just insert an echo statement before each block to find out *which* block is causing the problem, then start inserting more debug statements *within* that block until you narrow it down to the actual line.

You may also want to look at the [FAQ](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_faq.htm), especially the bit that states upping the PHP memory limits may assist with larger images. There is also the [forums](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_forum.htm) but I see [you've already started to go down that route](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_forum.htm?php_class_upload_forum_id=4264&php_class_upload_forum_thread_id=4264) :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> : What do rocket scientists say in this situation?

Comment: They probably say "Houston, we have a problem."

Comment: My drinking team has a rocket problem.

Comment: No, that is what an astronaut says. A rocket engineer says "oh so that is what that widget did" in response to "Houston, we have a problem".

Comment: Thanks for this @paxdiablo. The $image_name and $save_directory I have outputted and they look ok to me with nothing unusual showing. I'm starting to think it might be a memory limit.

Answer (score 1):

What is set to in your php.ini - this for example will show almost any error.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Comment: Cheers. I changed it to e_all & ~e_notice and I'm not getting anything . Thanks anyways.